# Boost multi_index_container with composite_key and bitwise-and comparison

Tags: c++, boost, multi-index, boost-multi-index

I want to achieve something like this with boost multi_index_container and composite_key:

```
struct LogicalAnd {
    bool operator()(const int& argVal1, const int& argVal2) const {
        return int(argVal1 & argVal2) == argVal1;
    }
};

template<class T, class Enable = void>
class FooContainer;

template <class T>
struct FooContainer<T,typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_base_of<IFoo, T> >::type> {
    typedef multi_index_container<
            boost::shared_ptr<T>,
            indexed_by<
            hashed_non_unique<
            composite_key<
            T,
            const_mem_fun<T,int,&T::getKey1>,
            const_mem_fun<T,int,&T::getKey2>
    >,
    composite_key_equal_to<
    LogicalAnd,
    LogicalAnd
    >
    >
    >
    > shared_ptr_type;
};
```

Knowing that:

```
namespace CustomKey {
    typedef enum {
        VAL1 = 0x00000001,
        VAL2 = 0x00000002,
        ALL = 0xFFFFFFFF
    } type;
}
```

The goal is to be able to perform the following:

```
container.find(boost::make_tuple(CustomKey::VAL1, CustomKey::ALL));
```

Which would allow me to retrieve all elements for which LogicalAnd returns true.

**The problem is that I can't manage to get my LogicalAnd comparator to work with my multi_index_container.**

I can get it to build by adding a composite_key_hash right before composite_key_equal_to:

```
composite_key_hash<
      boost::hash<int>,
      boost::hash<int>
>
```

But **find** operation does not work as expected so it does not change much...

I've searched boost documentation, and I've tryed various implementations, but I'm getting drown in the amount of information...

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If it helps, here's a test program:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3a2271c5ca9faba423da8141e00ba850-4f0e144d2529f0880899ab58231ebbe3

Comment: does anyone have an idea at least? :)

Comment: Still looking for a lead at least?

Comment: You haven't actually shown what the problem is. What build errors do you get? _How_ does `find` not work as expected?

Comment: Hello, I linked a test program above http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3a2271c5ca9faba423da8141e00ba850-4f0e144d2529f0880899ab58231ebbe3 . As mentioned, I'm not getting any build error as long as I specify a `composite_key_hash`, but I would expect find to return an item which matches my `LogicalAnd::operator`. Unfortunatelly, as demonstrated in the linked code, it doesn't work because `find` does not return any entry.

Comment: I'm not keen on linking code like this: it's open to link rot, and the code can be edited later. The code is supposed to go in the question so people can judge whether or not it's helpful to them in future problems. Anyway, with the linked code as it stands, have you considered just adding a print statement - or a breakpoint - inside your `LogicalAnd` to see what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a *hash* for your multi-index.

That means the `LogicalAnd` comparator never gets called unless something is found in the right hash bucket.

`0x01` and `0xFF` don't hash to the same value *even though* `0x01 & 0xFF == 0x01`. That is, `LogicalAnd` would return true, but it's never invoked.

You would need a hash function which is invariant wrt. `LogicalAnd`, and I don't think that's possible. By design most hash functions are supposed to minimise collisions between different key values.

You need to come up with some different indexing system, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks again for helping, now that you explain it, it sounds quite logical! But then it pops my 2nd question: what kind of indexing system could help me achieve this goal? Do you have any in mind?

Comment: Neither of your questions clearly explain what your goal _is_, they just show some code that doesn't achieve it. Explaining your actual problem on programmers.stackexchange might be worth a try. AS for structures that allow the sort of lookup you want, you could try a Trie.